# How to find rows where subquery string contains main query string?

Tags: sql-server, string, csv, sql-server-2008, subquery

For example, here are 2 tables with 1 row each:

Table Person

```
id   age
0    30 
1    41
2    15
```

Table People

```
ids    group
0,2    a
1      b
```

How would I make this query work?

```
SELECT id, age FROM Person WHERE ID like (select ids FROM People WHERE ids = '0,2')
```

This should list id 0 and 2 rows from the first table, i.e. any ID contained in "0,2"

```
id   age
0    30 
2    15
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first effort should go into fixing your data model. You should not be storing multiple numeric values in a string column.

If a person may belong to a single group, you can just add a column in the `person` table that represents the `id` of the relevant group:

- Table groups:

```
id   name
1    a
2    b
```

- Table person:

```
id   age   group_id
1    30    1
2    41    1
3    15    2
```

If a person may belong to may groups, you should have a separate table, where each `(id, grp)` tuple is stored on a separate row.

- Table groups:

```
id   name
1    a
2    b
```

- Table person:

```
id   age
1    30 
2    41
3    15
```

- Table person_groups:

```
id_person    id_group
1            1
2            1
3            1
3            2
```

With both set-ups, it is easy to write a query that retrieves the member of a given group, or to join the tables together.

---

As far as your current design is concerned: I think that you are looking for a join condition across the tables. One option is:

```
SELECT pn.id, pn.age 
FROM Person pn 
INNER JOIN People pe ON ',' + pe.ids + ',' LIKE '%,' + pn.id + ',%'
WHERE pe.group = 'a'
```

Or using an `exists` condition:

```
SELECT pn.* 
FROM Person pn 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM People pe 
    WHERE
        ',' + pe.ids + ',' LIKE '%,' + pn.id + ',%'
        AND pe.group = 'a'
)
```